# Detect salesforce forms spam

Tags: jquery, forms, salesforce

To my knowledge, salesforce doesn't allow you to detect spammers on their servers.  What's the best way to pre-empt it on a browser?

Here's my solution...

Salesforce and other 3rd party forms will use hidden fields to identify the customer and their data.  e.g. Salesforce requires this field in the form...

```
<input name="oid" type="hidden" value="YOUR SECRET CODE">
```

Since spammer bots don't generally run javascript or use a mouse.  I ensure the value is invalid in the form unless a mouse is hovering over the submit button.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $oid = $('form input[name=oid]');
    var $submit = $('form input[name=Submit]');

    $submit.hover(function(){
        //only valid oid when human hovers and clicks, spammer's will just POST
        $oid.val("00D7" + "9999999" + "9RMZ");  
    },function(){
        $oid.val("SPAMMER");
    });
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: btw, that's not my oid and it's not valid.

Comment: What about adding a `.submit` handler, calling `.preventDefault()` and changing the form action to another page and then submitting yourself?

Comment: Why not do it on page load rather than on hover?

Comment: both good suggestions... ben, if I was going to write another handler, I could just create my own form altogether and then submit to salesforce from the mid-tier.  Werewolf, yes, I suppose the hover, etc. is unnecessary if we can assume that spammers aren't running any javascript.  good point!